# C regular expression to validate hostname, right expresion but wrong output

Tags: c, regex, hostname

Using this code to simply check if C char pointer contains a valid hostname, I checked if the regular expresion is correct and I guess so, but in C the output I recieve is "No match".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    char *host = "www.google.es";
    regex_t regex;
    char regularExpresion[] = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";

    regcomp(&regex, regularExpresion, 0);

    if(!regexec(&regex, host, 0, NULL, 0))
        printf("Match");
    else
        printf("No match");
}
``
```

Comment: You just need `regcomp(&regex, regularExpresion, REG_EXTENDED);`

Comment: Just a feedback: are you sure you need a regular expression for this? They are quite expensive computationally,  writing a C function that does the check seems a more reasonable approach (and for sure will be way faster).

Comment: Nitpick, a trailing dot is legal (e.g. `google.es.`) but your regex doesn't match it.